# Download/Copy tar.gz File from S3 to EC2

Tags: amazon-s3, gzip, tar, cp

When I download a tar.gz file from AWS S3, and then I try to untar it, I am getting the following error:

```
tar -xzvf filename_backup_jan212021_01.tar.gz

gzip: stdin: not in gzip format

tar: Child returned status 1
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
```

When I check what type of file it is, I get this:

```
file filename_backup_jan212021_01.tar.gz
filename_backup_jan212021_01.tar.gz: ASCII text
```

This is the command I am using to copy the file from S3 to my EC2:

```
aws s3 cp s3://bucket_name/filename_backup_jan212021_01.tar.gz .
```

Please, help me find a solution to extract a tar.gz file after downloading it from AWS S3.

Comment: your `s3 cp` is failing or is not a gzip file. What does `cat filename_backup_jan212021_01.tar.gz` say?

Comment: This is the output of cat:  `cat filename_backup_jan212021_01.tar.gz
/home/ec2-user/file_delete_01.txt
/home/ec2-user/file_jan2021.txt
/home/ec2-user/filename_backup_jan1.tar.gz
/home/ec2-user/filename_backup_jan1.txt
/home/ec2-user/filename_backup_jan2.tar.gz
/home/ec2-user/filename_backup_jan3.tar.gz`

Comment: can you please [edit] and add in those details to your question?

Comment: from the output it looks like filename_backup_jan212021_01.tar.gz is not a tar'd zip file at all, but just a text file.

Comment: Sathyajith Bhat: I believe you are correct.  This is the command I use to upload the file: `tar -cvzf * | aws s3 cp - s3://willie-s3-file-deletion/filename_backup_jan212021.tar.gz` . However, when I tar the file before uploading it, then I can download it and it works.  So, the problem is when I upload the file and tar it at the same time as indicated in the command.  It seems S3, since it is not a filesystem, behaves in such a way that it does not tar and gzips the file.  It leaves it as an ASCII text file when using this command. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
tar -xzvf filename_backup_jan212021_01.tar.gz

gzip: stdin: not in gzip format
file filename_backup_jan212021_01.tar.gz
filename_backup_jan212021_01.tar.gz: ASCII text
```

`cat filename_backup_jan212021_01.tar.gz`

```
/home/ec2-user/file_delete_01.txt
/home/ec2-user/file_jan2021.txt
/home/ec2-user/filename_backup_jan1.tar.gz
/home/ec2-user/filename_backup_jan1.txt
/home/ec2-user/filename_backup_jan2.tar.gz
/home/ec2-user/filename_backup_jan3.tar.gz
```

---

All of these indicate that the file that was uploaded to S3 itself is not gzip'd tar file, rather just a plain text file uploaded with a `.tar.gz` filename. While filenames and extensions are used to indicate content type to humans, computers think otherwise :)

You can create the file with

```
tar cvzf <archive name> </path/to/files/to/be/tarred> && aws s3 cp <bucket path> <archive name>
```

to create the archive and upload it to S3, and use the commands you mention in the question to download them. Of course replace the placeholders with the proper names and such

Comment: Hi, do you have a Java SDK V2 alternate for this aws s3 cp command ?